# Trouble using FutureTask for Asynchronous proceedures

Tags: java, asynchronous, futuretask

In my Java web app I have a method which ends out about 200 emails. Because of email server delay the whole process takes about 7 minutes. This bulk email sending has to take place as the result of user action. I of course don't want the user to have to wait that long before they are forwarded to the next, not mention that Apache times out anyway, so I am attempting to implement FutureTask to get the process to run in a separate thread while proceed with the rest of the code like this:

```
Some code;

Runnable r = (Runnable)new sendEmails(ids);
FutureTask task = new FutureTask(r, null);
Thread t = new Thread(task);
t.start();

Some more code;
```

The app, however, still waits for the FutureTask to finish before proceeding. I am open to the idea that this also not the best way to run some code on the side in another thread while continuing with the rest of the script. Are there better ways/How do I make this one work?

Comment: This should not be blocking unless you are calling `get` on the task somewhere in the `Some more code` block.

Comment: Do you want to do some actions after the thread finishes its job? and what do you mean by `The app, however, still waits for the FutureTask to finish before proceeding`? There is no blocking call in your code.

Comment: I am not calling get and I have no need for a return. What is mean is that when I call this code `Some more code` (which is just a call forwarding the the user to a page) doesn't execute until the Runnable is done.

Comment: Fixed it.  `private class sendLGORejectionEmails implements Runnable {
  private final String ids;
  private sendLGORejectionEmails(String param) {
    ids = param;
  }
  public void run() {
    Send the emails;
  }
}`  Thanks for the help @Chris K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are spinning up 200+ threads in a for loop. That will place a high burden on the machine, and due to the size of each stack that is allocated with each thread it will not take too many threads before the JVM runs out of memory, initially causing much GC and JVM locking up and then potentially under high enough load, a crash.

Sadly this may or may not explain why your code is waiting for the FutureTasks to complete. It may only appear to be waiting to due thrashing by creating/scheduling so many threads; but then again it may not. There could very well be something else synchronizing your code that has been cut out of the snippet above.

A way for you to find if there is a tricksy synchronisation hiding somewhere would be to hit ctrl-break while running the code (assuming that you are running from a command line, intellij/eclipse both have a stack dump icon that is handy). This will cause a stack dump for every thread in the system to appear. By doing this you will be able to find the user thread that is waiting for the future tasks to complete, and it will say which monitor it is waiting on. If it is not waiting, then you have a different problem. For example the system thrashes creating so many threads in short order that it appears to lock up or some such for a short period of time.

But first I would avoid the excessive Thread creation part, as that could be masking the issue. I suggest using code similar to the following:

```
ExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() 
scheduler.submit( task )
```

Comment: The for loop isn't outside of the above code it's inside the sendEmails function. I've tried some Executors prior, but I'll try your arrangement and see if it works.

Comment: Seem it sill waits for the task to finish before moving on.

Comment: I am getting this error message however: java.lang.ClassCastException: my.application.CurrentClass$sendEmails cannot be cast to java.lang.Runnable

Comment: sendEmail looks like this: 'private class sendEmails {private sendEmails(String ids) { Code that sends the emails; }}'. When add implements Runnable to the class Runnable I have to use run() to which I am having trouble passing the ids variable.